# How to put a figure correctly in required place

Tags: floats

I'm using `t` to place the `figure` on top, I find it shifted downwards for more than half a page leaving the above part empty. Any help?

Comment: Well, any code? Sorry, but I can only guess you mean you are using `figure[t]`, right? Better you show us a compilable minimal code, that we can copy and test on our computer to help you. You can also add an screenshot (leave the ! out, one with more rep can reactivate it). Welcome to this side!

Comment: You can definitely force it to the top of the next page using \afterpage and\ captionof instead of figure.

Comment: 1) below the figure, what do you have? (if the page contents is only figure that's mean latex can't use option t and so it float your figure to a page)  2) what happen if you replace `\includegraphics{image}` with `\fbox{\includegraphics{image}}`

Comment: @Rana the question is closed now, but you still can edit it or comment it to add more informations, it can be reopen if necessary.